# Paypal Payment Standard in Magento cart page?

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, paypal, paypal-express, paypal-standard

I need to integrate paypal payment standard in magento cart page. **I don't want to use express checkout**. Because it again redirects to magento site for billing information and order conformation.

Below process is my requirement:

```
 1. user add a product to cart
 2. User click the paynow button in cart page
 3. User redirect to Paypal Login Page.
 4. After User login with paypal, confirm and pay the amount.
 5. User Redirect to magento thankyou page (order success page).
```

Is there any option in magento?

Comment: And when do you plan to get the billing (and shipping) address from the customer?

Comment: @Marius our product is downloadable product so we don't need billing and shipping address.

Answer (score 3):

The flow you describe is **exactly** the **Paypal Express** process in Magento.
The flow for **Paypal Standard** is:

1. user adds a product to the cart
2. user clicks proceed to checkout
3. user enters shipping address and clicks continue
4. user enters billing address and clicks continue
5. user selects shipping method and clicks continue
6. user enters the payment information, that is Paypal, and clicks continue
7. user views the order review section and clicks place order
8. user is redirected to the Paypal website
9. user logs in and confirms payment
10. user is redirected back to the Magento store success page